# Deploying .net MVC SQL Server CE to AppHarbor 404'ing

Tags: entity-framework, deployment, sql-server-ce, setup-deployment, appharbor

I'm trying to deploy a .net MVC app to AppHarbor. This is the first time I have used it and am having issues getting it work. I just get a 404 page. The errors tab shows nothing. I thought it might be something to do with the fact I'm using SQL Server CE so I went through this http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/04/24/automatic-migrations-with-entity-framework-4-3 and still no change.

I'm at a bit of a dead end at the moment so help would be greatly appreciated. If you need code samples just let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Are there any details in the 404? Please post a link to the app if you can.

Comment: No details in the 404 and no errors are show - working on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason that I haven't figured out yet this wouldn't work when pushing from a branch. As soon as I merged into master and pushed the deploy worked.

Comment: By default, we only deploy builds off the master branch. You can specify alternative tracking branches if you want: http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/managing-environments